# Column width is not fully filled after reordered

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a website based on unequal column, the site divided by `.col-md-2` and `.col-md-10` and it's look like this:

```
-------------------------------------
|Side       | Content               |
|           |                       |
|           |                       |
-------------------------------------
```

And then I want divide the content again into 2 unequal columns with `<aside>`, I want it has same layout styling, so inside `.col-md-10`, i uses `.col-md-8` for `Content` and `col-md-4` for `<aside>`, so it's look like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
|Side       | Content           | Aside |
|           |                   |       |
|           |                   |       |
-----------------------------------------
```

Inside `Content` I want to fill it with `<article>`, and each of it has `Detail` and I want put it on `Side` position while the content `<article>` still inside the `Content`.

To achieve this, I split `<article>` into 2 unequal columns again and pull each of them, so it uses `.col-md-pull-4 .col-md-4` and `.col-md-pull-4 .col-md-8`, and currently, it looks like:

```
-----------------------------------------
|Side       | Content           | Aside |
|(Detail)   | (Article)     *|  |       |
|           |                   |       |
-----------------------------------------
```

the layout works as expected, however the Article width only reach until `*|`
if i use `.col-md-pull-4 .col-md-12` on `<article>` content, it will looks like this

```
-----------------------------------------
|Side       | Content           | Aside |
|(Detail)   |                   |       |
|           | (Article)         |       |
|           |                   |       |
-----------------------------------------
```

The `article` has full width, but it create a new "row"
the output i **want** is:

```
-----------------------------------------
|Side       | Content           | Aside |
|(Detail)   | (Article)         |       |
|           |                   |       |
-----------------------------------------
```

### Update

Here is my current code on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/MIApiu9v0g)

### Progress

I haven't figure out how to do this, but basically, what i want is pull a column outside of its container / parent and fill the container with another column, if you think i was doing it wrong, provide a correct way to achieve this kind of layout is very appreciated.

**Update 2**
Finally I ended up messing with `margin-left` property with minus values, since it displayed incorrectly under specific resolution, i have to use media queries to workaround against it.

If there are better ways to achieve this kind of layout, correct me how to  implement this will be very appreciated

Comment: Do you think you could provide us with your code using http://www.bootply.com

Comment: I updated the question, thanks for suggestion

Comment: You forgot the link! You added "here is my current code" but it doesn't link anywhere!

Comment: @TomNolan I'm sorry, but can you help me now? can't find solution of this question